# Can I calculate loss on specific output value with pytorch binary classifier

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am building a binary classifier.

I want to calculate loss on predicted value 1 only, ignoring 0.

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
preds = model(inputs)
#ignore preds with value 0 and labels with the 0 value index
loss = criterion(preds, labels)
```

I am not sure, if the network can converge theoretically too.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:tensorflow]?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

There is `weight` for BCELoss.

For your case,

```
loss_w = labels  # ignore labels with the 0 value index
loss_w = loss_w * (pred > 0).float()  # ignore preds with values 0

loss = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy(preds, labels, weight=loss_w)
```